# Printing recursive all node-fetch operations info at once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following javascript code in which I am fetching github profile information for the users presented in an array.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');                                                
const users = ["nayabbashasayed", "AmruthPillai"]                                   

const getGithubProfiles = (users) => {
    let userGitProfiles = [];
    users.forEach(user => {                                                         
        const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + user;                         
        fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(body => {                           
            userGitProfiles.push(body);                                             
        });                                                                         
    });
    console.log(userGitProfiles);
}                                                                                   

getGithubProfiles(users);
```

I am using node to run the code.

Because of async nature, the line of code `console.log(userGitProfiles);` printing first resulting in the output `[]` and then the fetch operations are happening.

How do I wait for all the operations to finish and then print all info at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uese Promise.all to fetch all users profiles and get single array

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const users = ["nayabbashasayed", "AmruthPillai"]

const getGithubProfiles = (users) => {
    let userGitProfiles = [];
    let Q = []
    users.forEach(user => {
        const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + user;
        Q.push(fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
    });
    return Promise.all(Q)
}

getGithubProfiles(users).then(
    userProfiles => console.log(userProfiles)
);
```